# Response.ContentType = "text/xml" causes XML attributes construct error

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, handler

I have a C# `ashx` handler that will do some processes and then generate an `XML` output which should be parsed and sent to the server.

The problem is when I try to set the context Response to `txt/xml` it will generate the following error:

> This page contains the following errors:
>
> error on line 1 at column 226: attributes construct error
>
> Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error

It may look that the problem is with generated `XML` which may be not formatted well, but I've checked that by getting the output as a string then I used a validator and it was fine.

Any suggestions please to figure it out?

XML Output:

```
<Response>
<GetDigits action='http://domain/Handler.ashx?ivrlevel=9&amp;language=arb&amp;isOperation=false&amp;dayFrom=3&amp;dayTo=3&amp;hourFrom=12&amp;hourTo=2&amp;minFrom=30&amp;minTo=20&amp;enteredMobileNumber=66355356'>
    <Play>http://domain/AllClips/enterednumberis_arb.mp3</Play>
    <Play>http://domain/AllClips/6.mp3</Play>
    <Play>http://domain/AllClips/6.mp3</Play>
    <Play>http://domain/AllClips/3.mp3</Play>
    <Play>http://domain/AllClips/5.mp3</Play>
    <Play>http://domain/AllClips/5.mp3</Play>
    <Play>http://domain/AllClips/3.mp3</Play>
    <Play>http://domain/AllClips/5.mp3</Play>
    <Play>http://domain/AllClips/6.mp3</Play>
    <Play>http://domain/AllClips/numberconfirmation_arb.mp3</Play>
</GetDigits>
```

Comment: We're going to need to see some xml

Comment: You've reformatted the xml for posting - there isn't a column 226 in what you've shown. From googling, it looks like this error can come when whitespace is missing from somewhere that whitespace is expected to be. Show us the actual xml that gives this error.

Comment: The encoding is "utf-16" which is giving the error.  How are you reading file in c#?